# First tab closes when I open the second tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

My jQuery script is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
                    {

                        $("#accordions-727.accordions").accordion({
                            collapsible: true, active: "false", 
                            event: "click",
                            heightStyle: "content",
})
                    })
```

So when I open the first tab and leave it open, and then when I open the second tab the first one closes..How can I make the first tab stays open when opening the other tabs?

Comment: The core functionality of `accordion` is to collapse the unfocused tab(s). I do not think there is any easy way to customize as you are looking. You might create your own instead of using jQuery UI. Here is a tutorial: http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-an-accordion-with-html-css-jquery

Comment: ok thank you Patrick